# Change the address of stay after receiving Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, hotels, borders

I received a Schengen tourist visa through the embassy of France, in my itinerary I specified the hotel that I'll be staying in, now, my French friend offered me to stay at his place instead of the hotel.

I am wondering if I'll cancel my hotel reservation and stay at his place, is there a chance of getting into any kind of trouble at the border during entry for that?

My trip is only 4 days long.

Comment: Normally your friend would have to get a letter from the prefecture that he's hosting you to support your Schengen application. From personal experience (*not an answer !*) I've never been asked about accommodation details when entering France

Comment: Yes, I read that info, but it might take up to a month to get that letter from police. There is just simply not enough time for that.

Comment: I am just wondering if they'll ask me at the border where am I staying and I'll specify different place than is on my profile.

Comment: Technically the IO can as you anything, I'm not sure they have the details of your visa application. They usually care more about you leaving than where you're staying

Comment: Did you ask at the embassy that processed your application?

Comment: nope, haven't yet.

Comment: Sometimes the border police may ask you the address of where you are staying. i guess it is better to follow the rules as per your plan. It is not worth to take big risks, for saving small money. Usually when you stay at hotels, they automatically register your information with the police.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the same and I never got into trouble at the border. Usually, they might ask the address of your accommodation and I gave mine which was different than I told the embassy because I got a better deal. And I got no problem with that. However, if you're going to stay at your friend's place I'd suggest have a copy of his passport and his cell phone number with the address to present at the border just in case the immigration asks you. If you can specify clearly and confidently that he's your friend and you will be leaving the country at the date you specified. I believe it should be enough. However, I'm speaking from my past experience.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I am gonna do.